# PyScripter - Run Multiple instances of the same python 2.7 64 bit

Tags: multiple-instances, pyscripter

PyScripter is easily the best IDE I have come across for interactive work - especially with its ability to connect to remote engines.

It allows me to open multiple instances of pyscripter, each is tied to a different version (I have 3.3, 2.7 64 bit and 32 bit on my machine).

Question: Can I open multiple instances of pyscripter tied to 2.7 64 bit? Would help m enormously as I have huge amounts of ram and could easily work on two or three projects at a time.

Going to the command prompt and requesting PyScripter -N gives me a new instance as suggested at

[https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/pyscripter/0ebFUx6h7Z4][1]

, but it seems to default to 3.3  - but does open multiple instances of 3.3. I am not to familiar with how PyScripter picks out which version of python to tie to. Any help is most appreciated!

Update: 
Removing 3.3. seems to get me the multiple instances of 2.7 - but would want to have a solution that allows me to have 3.3 installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried adding --python27 -N and I was able to start up two instances of PyScripter.
I then ran --python26 -N, and started a 3rd instance of PyScripter that ran Python26.

```
...\PyScripter.exe --PYTHON27 -N
...\PyScripter.exe --PYTHON27 -N
...\PyScripter.exe --PYTHON26 -N
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Who would have thunk it - great answer thanks! Now to put it in a batch file.